# Passive voice complication,or something like this

Tags: passive-voice

Grammarians,
I would like to ask you if there is a difference between these two sentences:

- I remember being invited...
- I remember having been invited...

Are they grammatically correct? Do they mean the same, or have some differences in their meanings?
In my native language (Russian),both of them sound the same. We do not care much about tenses, and understand many things just from the context.
Many thanks beforehand,
X.

Comment: The second would be used to set the invitation further back in time (I was by that time working enthusiastically for Spell, though I remember having been invited to join the board of Osso). But otherwise, they're largely interchangeable.

Comment: Of course there must be a difference between your sentences, unless the basic structure of the English language is faulty.

Is that much clear, or not?

Answer (score 1):

One could split hairs and say that the ‘being invited’ version recalls the act (of inviting) while the ‘having been invited’ version recalls the fact, but in normal conversation they convey pretty much the same idea.

Comment: Good point +1. 'I remember being invited' would, for me, carry a picture of the point at which I was invited. That is I would remember the actual meeting, telephone call or letter in which the invitation was conveyed. 'I remember having  being invited' on the other hand would mean that I recalled the fact that I had been invited but could not, necessarily, recall when, how or by whom the invitation was made.